# How to convert any datatype other than string to String in mule-config.xml

Tags: java, mule

For example in `mule-config.xml` file, if we have

---Start

```
spring:bean id="objPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool"

spring:property name="whenExhaustedAction" value="#

{org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW}"
```

---End

Here, WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW is public static final byte and its value is 2.

Now when I do `mule -config mule-config.xml`, I get following error

Error:

```
org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Initialisation Failure: Error creating bean with name 'videoRequestSAXParserObjectPool' defined in URL [file:/home/joshlabs/codebase/collider-server-tidal/src/main/resources/mule-config-pingback.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [byte] for property 'whenExhaustedAction'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW}"
```

Please help  me how can I convert "byte" datatype to "String" datatype.

Thanks,
Prince

Comment: It's complaining about a bean named "videoRequestSAXParserObjectPool": I imagine it's the one named objPool in the (strangely looking) configuration fragment above? Anyways: you're trying to use Spring EL in a Mule config, knowing that Spring EL's syntax is similar to the Mule EL one. There may be a conflict there. Mule version?

Comment: sorry, bean id is "videoRequestSAXParserObjectPool" only & not "objPool"....By mistake I wrote "objPool" there...
I am using Mule 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule 2.1.2 depends on Spring 2.5.6, which doesn't support Spring Expression Language (SpEL). In Spring 2, you'll need to use [util:constant](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-constant) to read the WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW value and inject it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an SpEL problem, not a Mule one.

When you type a class name, SpEL doesn't know if that is a class or not. So it's returning 
"org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" as a string. You should use the [T operator](http://#%7BT%28org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool%29.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW%7D%22).

Try this :

```
#{T(org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool).WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW}"
```

Comment: I am getting the same error: Error creating bean with name 'videoRequestSAXParserObjectPool' defined in URL [file: /src/main/resources/mule-config-pingback.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [byte] for property 'whenExhaustedAction'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{T(org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool).WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW}"